# Sorting a string using STL

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to sort the characters of a string using `C++ STL` and came up with this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


int main() 
{
    using namespace std;
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    string arr[] = {"jajajaj"};
    vector<string> v(arr, arr+2);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (it=v.begin(); it<v.end(); it++) {
      cout << *it;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

But unfortunately its **not sorting properly when the array contains single element**. How to do it using STL.
Please help.

Comment: Your string array has one single element. You are trying to instantiate a vector of two elements with it, in the process accessing it out of bounds. That is *undefined behaviour*. You shouldn't expect anything sensible to happen when you run this program.

Comment: this is bad: `vector<string> v(arr, arr+2)` - `arr` is `string[1]`

Comment: Please can you explain it a bit, i am new to C++ STL all together.

Comment: @c_coder: Don't use raw arrays. Use `std::vector<std::string>` if the size is dynamic or `std::array<std::string>` if it's fixed and if you use C++11.

Answer (score 7):

You can sort the string using `std::string` class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     string str = "jajajaj";
     sort(str.begin(), str.end());
     cout << str;
     return 0;
}
```

Hope this might be helpful.

Comment: what header is that??

Comment: @OMGtechy: Trivially identifiable using a website called Google: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/8387 Doesn't really belong in this answer though

Answer (score 5):

If you need a string, use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) :

(I used a for-range loop to make the code cleaner)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    string s = {"jajajaj"};
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    for (auto c : s)
      cout << c;

    return 0;
}
```

**Outputs**:

> aaajjjj

---

**Note:**

Your current code is not working because, as commented, you create a vector of size 2 out of an array of size 1, which has undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, the title suggests otherwise.

Comment: So it does, downvote moved to question instead of answer

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing a `std::string` with an array of chars.

```
 int main() 
 {
     using namespace std;

     string arr = "jajajaj";
     vector<char> v(arr.begin(), arr.end());
     sort(v.begin(), v.end());
     vector<char>::iterator it;
     for (it=v.begin(); it<v.end(); ++it) {
       cout << *it;
    }
     return 0;
 }
```

I haven't tested that, but it should work....

#### UPDATE:

Alternately, we could just sort the string's character directly:  (Thanks guys!)

```
 int main() 
 {
     using namespace std;

     string arr = "jajajaj";
     sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
     cout << arr;
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Or you could just sort the string.

Comment: `std::string` is not immutable.

Comment: @juanchopanza: You're right -- I confused C++ strings with C#'s immutable string..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sort()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function. sort() exists in [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header file

```
        #include<bits/stdc++.h>
        using namespace std;

        int main()
        {
            ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
            string str = "sharlock";

            sort(str.begin(), str.end());
            cout<<str<<endl;

            return 0;
        }
```

### Output:

```
achklors
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort a string, just input string from the user and use the sort() in STL for it.

```
   #include<bits/stdc++.h>
   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
    string arr; 
    cin >>arr;
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    cout <<arr;
   }
```

See the sample image below for the output with input string as "Michael".